# Firebase Google Auth in Unity - cannot find symbol GoogleSignInResult

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I've recently integrated Firebase into my Unity application and it's been great so far, but I am stuck trying to get Google Auth working (Android).

```
error: cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
```

The Firebase Auth docs direct me through a few pages and eventually to this
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

following the steps on this page resolves the GoogleSignInResult but causes other errors:

it looked like I needed to add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
```

but that gave me

```
Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
```

so I added

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

which then gave me this error which I couldn't seem to fix.

```
AndroidManifest.xml:6:19-87 Error:
Attribute provider#com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider@authorities value=(com.jroddev.application.sandbox.firebaseinitprovider) from [:firebase-common-11.0.0:] AndroidManifest.xml:6:19-87
is also present at [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:6:19-78 value=(com.google.firebase.firebaseinitprovider).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-203 to override.
```

I export an Android Gradle Project from Unity, copy in my Android/Java files and then try to run **gradle assembleRelease** (commandline and through Android Studio).

Has anyone experienced this or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this AssetStore plugin to solve my problem

[Google Login iOS & Android](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/94517)